# Using PdfiumViewer in a .NET standard Assembly

Tags: .net-standard-2.0, pdfium

I am trying to split a pdf into seperate images using PdfiumViewer and keep errors saying:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS7069  Reference to type 'Image' claims it is defined in 'System.Drawing', but it could not be found
> Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS7069  Reference to type 'Graphics' claims it is defined in 'System.Drawing', but it could not be found

in the line below:

`using (Image image = pdfDocument.Render(pageIndex, 300, 300, true))`

I tried most combinations of Pdfium assmblies using nuget but still havent found a way to fix it.